# Using a model manager isn't working but querying using a filter in in the view does, where am I going wrong?

Tags: django, django-models, filter, django-queryset

I am trying to create a view to show all friend requests for a user. I am able to render the requests in a view if I use a plain filter method but moving to the model and using a model manager doesn't find the objects that are found by the filter method in the view. To me, they seem the same, so I must be misunderstanding something.

Trying to use the model manager in the view to query, the query doesn't return anything like so:

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
rec_req = FriendRequest.objects.received_requests(to_user=profile.user)
```

However, if I use the filter method in the view directly I get the objects like so:

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
rec_req = FriendRequest.objects.filter(
        to_user=profile.user
    )
```

#models.py

```
class FriendRequestManager(models.Manager):
    def received_requests(self, to_user):
        rec_req = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=to_user, status='requested')
        return rec_req

class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    is_family = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    objects = FriendRequestManager()
```

I'd really appreciate the help because I am stuck.

TIA

Comment: From the first trial, the objects is the default manager, and is suppose to 'act' the same as your custom manger. Your second qs should be`rec_req = FriendRequest.received_requests.filter(
        to_user=profile.user
    )`

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you, that was an oversight on my part!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
class FriendRequest(models.Model):
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    is_family = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    objects = FriendRequestManager()

    @classmethod
    def received_requests(cls,to_user):
        rec_req = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=to_user,status='requested')
        return rec_req
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time but there isn't enough explanation for someone of my competence level, (I still need to learn about using the classmethods in this type of scenario) but I will definitely give it a try at a later date. For now, I have solved the problem with @Mugoma explanation.